# Filter SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The sample data is:

```
 

 l16seqno | l16lcode |  carrno |       ecarrno      | l16qty | reasoncode 

 32001    | 12       |  207620 | 370036873034035916 | 32     |    0 

 32269    | 12       |  207620 | 370036873034035916 | -32    |   800 

 39075    | 12       |  207620 | 370036873034035916 | 32     |    0 

 39074    | 12       |  207622 | 370036873034035923 | 32     |    0 

 32268    | 12       |  207622 | 370036873034035923 | -32    |   800 

 31999    | 12       |  207622 | 370036873034035923 | 32     |    0 

 32271    | 12       |  207624 | 370036873034035930 | -32    |   800 

 32005    | 12       |  207624 | 370036873034035930 | 32     |    0 
 
 39077    | 12       |  207624 | 370036873034035930 | 32     |    0
```

I  have logging of all the events in table Z02T1. Whenever I have l16lcode=12 – I am blocking or unblocking a pallet. When I block a pallet l16lqty feild is negative, and when I unblock – it is positive.

Reason codes can be found in Z02T2 table (can be connected to Z02T1 by l16seqno – a unique sequence number of each log record).

Z14T1 table contains info about pallets – pallet numbers.

My aim is to find two lines for each pallet i.e.

when blocked with code 800 ... and ... when unblocked with code 0

For this I have to find the nearest next record of l16lcode=12 for the same pallet with reason code 0 (after there was a record for this pallet with reason code 800).

The initial query I have made is:

```
select   Z02T1.datreg, Z02T1.l16seqno, Z02T1.l16lcode, Z02T1.divcode, Z02T1.carrno,
       Z14T1.ecarrno, Z02T1.l16qty, Z02T2.reascode from Z02T2
inner join Z02T1 on Z02T1.l16seqno=Z02T2.l16seqno
left outer join Z14T1 ON Z14T1.carrno=Z02T1.carrno
where Z02T1.l16lcode=12 
and (Z02T2.reascode=800 or Z02T2.reascode=0 )
order by Z14T1.ecarrno
```

How I can change this query to get one record with **reasoncode 800** and then very next record with **reasoncode 0** for same **ecarrno feild** ?

Comment: Is this sql-server OR oracle?  There is no PL/SQL remove tag.

Comment: @Hansen - which version of SS ?

Comment: It involves only SQL so it should run on all version of SS

Comment: Then remove the unnecessary tags.

Comment: Unnecessary tags have been removed

Comment: If it should run on ALL versions of SQL Server that would be back to 4.21 which was released about 20 years ago. Runing sql servers would go back to the 2005 version some people still seem to use. SO, which one is it?

Comment: @Tom Tom .. It is SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code that you could use to modify your existing query.

Be aware that this example filters on the first occurance of `reasoncode=800` and then subfilters on the first occurance of `reasoncode=0` that has a `l16seqno` greater than the `reasoncode=800` record.

```
CREATE TABLE reasons (
  l16seqno int NOT NULL,
  carrno int NOT NULL,
  reasoncode int NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO reasons
  (l16seqno, carrno, reasoncode)
VALUES
  (1, 1, 0),
  (2, 1, 800),
  (3, 1, 0),
  (10, 300, 0),
  (11, 300, 800),
  (12, 300, 0),
  (13, 300, 800),
  (14, 300, 0),
  (1003, 1212, 0),
  (1004, 1212, 800),
  (1005, 1212, 0),
  (1006, 1212, 0);

WITH cte1 (l16seqno, carrno, reasoncode, rownumber)
AS
(
  SELECT l16seqno, carrno, reasoncode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY carrno, reasoncode ORDER BY l16seqno)
  FROM reasons
  WHERE reasoncode = 800
),
cte2 (l16seqno, carrno, reasoncode, rownumber)
AS
(
  SELECT r.l16seqno, r.carrno, r.reasoncode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.carrno, r.reasoncode ORDER BY r.l16seqno)
  FROM reasons AS r
  INNER JOIN cte1 AS c ON r.carrno = c.carrno
  WHERE r.reasoncode = 0 AND r.l16seqno > c.l16seqno
)
SELECT r.l16seqno, r.carrno, r.reasoncode
FROM reasons AS r
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte1 AS c1 ON c1.l16seqno = r.l16seqno
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte2 AS c2 ON c2.l16seqno = r.l16seqno
WHERE c1.rownumber = 1
OR c2.rownumber = 1
ORDER BY r.carrno, r.l16seqno;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a432/1) of the sample code listed above.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Laszlo.. for your help ... I manged to make it work and it gives the desired result. So nice of you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
;with cte as
(
    Select  l16seqno
            ,l16lcode
            ,carrno
            ,ecarrno
            ,l16qty
            ,reasoncode
            ,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By ecarrno, reasoncode Order By l16seqno) rn
    From    MyTable
)
Select  l16seqno
        ,l16lcode
        ,carrno
        ,ecarrno
        ,l16qty
        ,reasoncode
From    cte
Where   rn = 1
Order By ecarrno asc, reasoncode desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Dave! Let me try it and then I will get back to you